# Will a windows mobile 6 app work on a windows ce 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I need to make an app for a windows ce 6 device, but i haven't find any emulators for this type of operating system and I don't have the device. I only get windows ce 5 or windows mobile 5 and 6 emulators. If a write the app for a windows mobile 6 can it be installed afterwards on a windows ce? will it work? They both use net framework 3.5. If not what can I do? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write your app against Windows CE not Windows Mobile!

Apps written, compiled against Windows Mobile have references to shell functions (aygshell) that are not available on WM.

You should get a Windows CE Platform SDK for the device you are writing for by the OEM. That should enable you to run an emulator.

see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee504799%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

BTW: you can run Compact Framework app on your PC without any change as long as they do not reference any CE only functions.